# The process cannot access the file 'XXX' because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, file, file-io

I get the following exception

```
Error Message:The process cannot access the file '....\folder\r.js' because it is being used by another process.    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)
   at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(String path, Encoding encoding, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, Int32 bufferSize)
   at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(String path, Encoding encoding)
   at System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(String path, Encoding encoding)
   at System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(String path)
   at PrepareEventDates()
```

---

My method :

```
protected HashSet<string> PrepareEventDates()
{
    HashSet<string> str = new HashSet<string>();
    WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
    string path = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings.Get("sss").ToString();
    webclient.DownloadFile(path, Server.MapPath("r.js"));
    String[] JSLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(Server.MapPath("folder/r.js"));
    String strDate = string.Empty;
    string toolTip = string.Empty;
    for (int i = 0; i < JSLines.Length; i++)
    {
        string result = JSLines[i];
        int methodBodyStart = JSLines[i].IndexOf("DefineEvent(");
        if (methodBodyStart >= 0)
        {
            methodBodyStart += "DefineEvent(".Length;
            int methodBodyEnd = JSLines[i].LastIndexOf(')');
            if (methodBodyEnd >= 0)
            {
                string methodBody = JSLines[i].Substring(methodBodyStart, methodBodyEnd - methodBodyStart);
                var twoParams = methodBody.Split(',')
                   .Select(x => x.Trim(' ', '\'')).Take(2);
                result = string.Join("|", twoParams.ToArray());
            }
        }
        str.Add(result);
    }

    return str;
}
```

Comment: How are you creating/writing to the `folder/r.js` file? Here you have only shown how you are reading from it: `String[] JSLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(Server.MapPath("folder/r.js"));` but it's usually the code that's opening the file for writing that might be poorly written and lock it. Also if this is inside a web application you should synchronize the access to those files. Imagine 2 parallel requests hitting your server. There are big chances that your files will be corrupted unless you use a `ReaderWriterLockSlim` to work with them.

Comment: Try to dispose webclient after job done.

Comment: The WebClient has nothing to do here. The WebClient is working with the `Server.MapPath("r.js")` file, not `Server.MapPath("folder/r.js")` which apparently is the one that's locked here. But, yes, in general it is good practice to wrap `IDisposable` resources (such as the WebClient in this case) in a `using` statement.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov you r right.

Comment: please give it a look at my answer. thanks

Comment: have you tried it? did it worked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is related with the `FileShare` option, as you can see by your StackTrace error, the method you use to read the lines, uses a `FileStream` object.

I suggest your to read the file, but do the instantiation of the `FileStream` yourself:

```
string contents = string.Empty;

using(FileStream fs = new FileStream("", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs))
       contents = sr.ReadToEnd();
```